# C++ - How do I add functions to work on a multitude of cases for a currency calculator?

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

```
For my currency calculator, I need to add 3 different types of functions-
1) enterCostUSD (I enter the cost in USD)
2) convertCost (convert the cost from USD to, say, rupees)
3) displayOutput (display the output of the new cost)
```

I have total 10 cases. How do I add the functions so that they apply to all
        10 cases?

Do I need to add them in the middle of each case?

This is one of the case, Do I need to do it in this way or there is any better way?

```
    case 1: //Finding cost in Altairian Dollars
    cout << "Enter the cost in US Dollars: ";
    cin >> enterCostUSD;
    altairianDollars = enterCostUSD*0.72
    cout << "$" << enterCostUSD << " is equal to " << altairianDollars   
    cout << "Thank You for using the Currency Calculator!" << endl;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is you have 10 cases where you are trying to convert the currency. So for that you have to create 10 cases like you mentioned in your question.

If any of the functionality which is common to all of your cases you can keep it in a function and call it from each `cases.`

Here printing output and converting currency are the functionality which can be put separate.

For eg:

```
 case 2: //Finding cost in Rupee
    CostUSD=enterUSDCost();//function 1
    conversion_rate=63.5;//for rupee
    Rupee = convertCost(CostUSD,conversion_rate);//function2
    displayOutput(enterCosstUSD,Rupee,"Rs");//function 3
    break;
```

These three functions need to be out of the scope of your main function, these are three separate function.

```
float enterCostUSD()
{
float USD_cost;
cout << "Enter the cost in US Dollars: ";
        cin >> USD_cost;
return USD_cost;
}
float convertCost(float USD, float rate)
{
return USD*rate;
}

void displayOutput(float enterCostUSD, float Rupee,string conversion_currency){
cout << "$" << enterCostUSD << " is equal to " << Rupee <<conversion_currency   ;

    cout << "Thank You for using the Currency Calculator!" << endl;
    }
```

If you like to develop better understanding of switch case follow this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)

Comment: take a tour by following link to know more about StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/tour :)